# Is it possible to download complete webpage using typhoeus instead of HTML only in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, typhoeus

I am using ruby to download a complete web page using typhoeus, but it downloads only HTML,

```
   request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
             "www.example.com",
             method: :get,
             headers: { Accept: "text/html" }
    )
```

response.body returns only HTML, Can I add any format to download complete webpage with its data which is being loaded via javascript? Or is there any other way to get the data?

Comment: Usually you're responsible for parsing the HTML with something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) and then fetching any resources you want after the fact. It's worth noting that the `wget` tool has a `-m` option that recursively spiders and downloads everything if you need a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: Via nokogiri , I used open but it too gets the html only as the webpage I am trying to parse is loading its data via javascript.

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with anything here? Once again, Nokogiri is an HTML parser. It is not a site downloader. If you need JavaScript for this to work you need to use [a headless browser](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/browser_testing), so good luck with that.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool unless you are willing to write a lot more code. As @tadman said, `wget -m` is a good solution. There are many different existing tools to do what you want but those are for you to discover and evaluate as asking for recommendations is off-topic. It'd probably help you if you studied how a browser renders a page by retrieving the elements, if you choose to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done in a single request. You need to parse the html to find all the images required and download them

Depending on what you are doing with this,  you may need to do the same for other assets on the page (eg css)

Comment: I need to get the content from webpage, which is loading via javascript, how to parse to get the data loaded via javascript?